# Caffe remove .cu implementation got compile errors

Tags: c++, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I am trying to revise SigmoidCrossEntropyLossLayer to my own version. I only implemented .cpp version. There was already a .cu file of SigmoidCrossEntropyLossLayer and it seems that I have to use the backword_gpu as my backward implementation. I tried to delete this .cu file and here is one of the errors popped out (actually all similar errors just with different bin files):

```
make: *** [.build_release/tools/compute_image_mean.bin] Error 1
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `caffe::SigmoidCrossEntropyLossLayer<double>::Backward_gpu(std::vector<caffe::Blob<double>*, std::allocator<caffe::Blob<double>*> > const&, std::vector<bool, std::allocator<bool> > const&, std::vector<caffe::Blob<double>*, std::allocator<caffe::Blob<double>*> > const&)'
```

Does anyone know how to let caffe neglects this single .cu file? I don't want to use it anymore in my project. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I found a way to do this which is call backward_cpu in backward_gpu. I can do it in this way but I am still wondering is there a neater way to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `Backward_gpu` and `Forward_gpu` declarations from the `sigmoid_cross_entropy_loss_layer.hpp` file.

The .cu file has the definitions for these virtual functions, so when you removed the .cu file, you had the virtual function declarations without the implementations.

You will also need to remove the following lines from your `sigmoid_cross_entropy_loss_layer.cpp` file:

```
#ifdef CPU_ONLY
STUB_GPU(WARPLossLayer);
#endif
```

This ensures your compiler doesn't create stubs for the `*_gpu` functions as this will cause Caffe to break since you removed the declarations in the header file.

You will also have to edit the tests accordingly.